# Управление проектом для разработчика

Tags: веб-программирование, agile, scrum, project-management

Я веб-разработчик, занимаюсь разработкой крупного проекта уже на протяжении года. По прогнозам, работы еще на год-полтора.

Разработкой я занимаюсь один, в редких случаях, подключаю еще 2-3х разработчиков.

Наш менеджер не справляется с управлением проекта,
и эта задача ложится на мои плечи.

Задач очень много, и делятся на следующие группы:

1. Задачи, которые понятно, что нужно делать, каким образом. Такие задачи мы оценили по трудозатратам.
2. Задачи, которые мы понимаем, как должны работать (какой должен быть результат), но пока не понимаем как их решать.
3. Задачи, которые мы не понимаем, как это должно точно работать, и каким образом их решать.

Задач, которые относятся ко 2 и 3 пункту достаточно много, и на текущем этапе, мы не можем бросить текущие задачи, а заниматься оценкой трудозатрат других задач, т.к. это займет много времени, и это включает в себя дополнительные встречи с клиентом, проработки каждой задачи, чтобы оценить.

Из-за таких задач, у нас у самих нет понимания, сколько еще будет длиться проект, и вообще нет никакого плана, кроме текущих оцененных задач.

Нужна какая-то методология, какие-то схемы работы, т.к. я не чувствую, что проект в моих руках. Хочется понимать, что все под контролем, что за чем следуем, какие этапы, и это также видел клиент.

Задачи поступают постоянно, и чаще всего очень приоритетные задачи, из-за которых приходится откладывать текущие задачи и работать с новой. Соответственно, сроки по задачам, которые были оценены срываются!

Задачи сыпятся из разных источников. Нет никакого контроля. Хаос.
Для контроля задач, я пробовал использовать Trello - не подошло, т.к. куча задач, нет понимая, какая задача сколько длится, и какая задача следующая.
Ms Project - не подошел, слишком сложен с точки зрения внесения изменений, добавления новых приоритетных задачи т.д.

С клиентом сейчас работаем по такой схеме:
на словах проговариваем какие задачи приоритетны среди всей каши, и занимаемся ими. И каждые два дня, клиент звонит и спрашивает что да как!! Это все надоело! Т.е. бывают задачи, на которые нельзя посмотреть визуально, это бэкенд, и такие задачи сложные, и могут длиться неделю и больше.

Господа, нужна помощь, хочется навести порядок! Создать план, накидать все задачи в какую-то систему, даже те, которые еще оценили, сделать хотябы предварительную, грубую оценку.

Чтобы я смог сказать клиенту, что все! теперь работаем по такой-то схеме, больше не звонить каждые два дня и не е**ть мозги, почему задача, которая еще в работе - не готова!

Какие подходят методологии для моей ситуации ? Какие инструменты? Что делать и как быть?

Comment: Просто удалите вопрос, если хотите его удалить, а не заменяйте текст цифрами

Comment: jira / agile - project managment